# Upgrading Cassandra from 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: cassandra

1. I upgraded Cassandra 2.0.9 to 2.1

Query on the index does not work after upgrading Cassandra from 2.0.9 to 2.1.
Anything that I am missing.

Query on the Primary Key works
Eg. select userid,name from user where userid='lll';

I have Indexed on "name" and if i query
select userid,name from user where name='abc'; Does not work.
This was working before Upgrade.

Comment: Procdure specified in Datastax upgrade Guide !!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `nodetool upgradesstables`?  Going by the steps give in the [DataStax Upgrade Guide](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html), that is the step that is most-often forgotten.

Otherwise, you can rebuild each index through nodetool.

```
nodetool rebuild_index MyKeyspaceName MyColumnFamilyName MyIndexName
```

Your indexes should work after that, but that will eat I/O and CPU, so it should be a last resort.  Definitely make sure that upgradesstables was run first.

Comment: Yes I did nodetool upgradesstables. I wrote an cql script to DROP INDEX and recreate INDEX. This worked.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above and it worked. Which method is good     a) nodetool rebuild_index MyKeyspaceName MyColumnFamilyName MyIndexName           OR                                                                 b) Use a CQL Script to DROP index and then CREATE index ?